# No type arguments expected for class Matcher

Tags: android, kotlin, android-espresso

I am trying to create a custom matcher for an espresso test. My code so far is:

```
private fun withCrossedOutText(): Matcher<View> {
    return object :  BoundedMatcher<View, TextView>(TextView::class.java) {
        override fun matchesSafely(item: TextView?): Boolean {
            // Code
        }

        override fun describeTo(description: org.hamcrest.Description?) {
            // Code
        }
    }
}
```

This gives an error on the first line saying

> No type arguments expected for class Matcher

I have tried removing `<View>` but this creates more issues.

Comment: Code looks alright, unless one of your types is ambiguous, maybe check if your `View` is a `android.view.View` for example..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was that the wrong Matcher package was imported. I was originally using regex Matcher but when I used Hamcrest Matcher the issue went away.